# AnimatedSwitcher not wroking with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, animation, riverpod

AnimatedSwitcher not wroking with Riverpod. I already tried 2 different approach.

## **first i used**

```
final online = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => true);
```

**
My Widget**

```
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    ref.read(online.notifier).state = !ref.watch(online),
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: const Duration(microseconds: 1000),
                    child: ref.watch(online)
                        ? SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/vectors/switch-on.svg",
                            height: 20.rw,
                            key: const ValueKey(2),
                          )
                        : SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/vectors/switch-off.svg",
                            height: 20.rw,
                            key: const ValueKey(1),
                          ))),
```

## **I also tried **

```
final online = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => true);
final switcher = StateProvider<Widget>((ref) => SvgPicture.asset(
      "assets/vectors/switch-on.svg",
      height: 20.rw,
      key: const ValueKey(1),
    ));
onSwitch(WidgetRef ref) {
  ref.read(switcher.notifier).state = ref.watch(online)
      ? SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/vectors/switch-off.svg",
          height: 20.rw,
          key: const ValueKey(2),
        )
      : SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/vectors/switch-on.svg",
          height: 20.rw,
          key: const ValueKey(1),
        );
  ref.read(online.notifier).state = !ref.watch(online);
}
```

**
My Widget**

```
 GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => onSwitch(ref),
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: const Duration(microseconds: 500),
                    child: ref.watch(switcher)))
```

## **Both didn't worked**

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using 1000 `microseconds` which is 0.0001 `second`.
Try to change the animation duration to something like 500 `milliseconds`.

```dart
duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
```

Also notice that you should use `!ref.read(online)` instead of `!ref.watch(online)` inside the `onTap` callback.

```dart
onTap: () => ref.read(online.notifier).state = !ref.read(online),
```

You may also consider using the `Notifier` instead.

```dart
// Define a Notifier
class OnlineStatusNotifier extends Notifier<bool> {
  @override
  bool build() => true;

  void toggle() => state = !state;
}

// Define a Notifier provider
final onlineStatusProvider = NotifierProvider<OnlineStatusNotifier, bool>(OnlineStatusNotifier.new);

// Invoke the Notifier's method
onTap: () => ref.read(onlineStatusProvider.notifier).toggle(),

// Consume the provider
ref.watch(onlineStatusProvider)
```

Comment: I can't believe i used microseconds. I was just to build to see it. Thank also Charles